# Windows Server 2012 inplace upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, upgrade

All

I'm trying to automate our virtual Machines that are currently running Windows '12 to either Server 16 or '19.

I'm Trying to get the ei.cfg File Working

At present I have

```
[EditionID]
ServerStandard
[Channel]
OEM
[VL]
0
```

This will kick off the process but the issue is that the process pauses on the option of OS Selection "Standard or Desktop Full ".

How does one select Full Desktop within the EI.CFG File?